# ANR with com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-anr-dialog

I have got this reported under an ANR error in my Google Play Console.

I'm using Ironsource network and Facebook ads mediation. I tried everything but have no clue.

Here is all the stack trace I got from the Console:

```
Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 2. Wait queue head age: 5971.9ms.), VisibleToUser 
com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity
```

this is the main thread

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x728615e0 self=0xaea84000
| sysTid=30076 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb25224a8
| state=S schedstat=( 38978911993 8299336927 117582 ) utm=2789 stm=1107 core=4 HZ=100
| stack=0xbe25c000-0xbe25e000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 0000000000018e68  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01  pc 00000000000477d7  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait(pthread_cond_internal_t*, 
pthread_mutex_t*, bool, timespec const*)+102)
#02  pc 0000000000037775  /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
#03  pc 0000000000037711  /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
#04  pc 000000000024dadb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat 
(Java_android_view_ThreadedRenderer_nSyncAndDrawFrame__J_3JI+138)
 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame (Native method)
 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:776)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3008)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2822)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2375)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1414)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6827)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:658)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6592)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?